# How to use the numeric value returned by a function?

Tags: bash, function, return-value

I have a function that returns a numeric value to indicate an error.

```sh
gimme_five() {
    return 5
}
```

Can I use this function *as a number* in an assignment?

That is, I would like to do something like the following

```sh
(( COUNT+=gimme_five ))
```

is this possible or must they always be separate statements, a la:

```sh
gimme_five
(( COUNT+=$? ))
```

Comment: The Q set as duplicate, does not have answers about using numerical return values directly, but instead about using general values *indirectly*. Here I am specifically asking if it is possible to use *numerical* values *directly*, or not.

Comment: A bash function does not have a return value. IMHO, the name _function_ for this construct is inappropriate; it should be called _procedure_ or _subroutine_ or something like that. When you do a `return 5`, it just sets the status code to 5 and returns to the caller.

Comment: `gimme_five() { echo 5; }; ((count += $(gimme_five)))`